# filter duplicate elements from an array using collection

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I don't resolve the processList error.
I am using collection to filter duplicate elements from an array and print as a list.
Form a list of numbers from 0-9.
Insert a new set of numbers from 0-5.

```
package programming;
    
    import java.awt.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    public class FillterDublicateElementFromArrayPrintList2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
            // Form a list of numbers from 0-9.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }
    
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }
    
            System.out.println("Input list : " + list);
            System.out.println("\nFiltered duplicates : " + processList(list));
        }
    
        public static Set<String> processList(List<String> listContainingDuplicates) {
    
            final Set<String> resultSet = new HashSet<String>();
            final Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>();
    
            for (String yourInt : listContainingDuplicates) {
                if (!tempSet.add(yourInt)) {
                    resultSet.add(yourInt);
                }
            }
            return resultSet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question. Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you get? Have you stepped through your code with the debugger?

Comment: The duplicated values are 0-4, not 0-5.

Comment: The way you did this, you will get all the elements that appear more than once in the input list.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely have logical problems in realizing your processList function, you can follow the following steps:

1. put all the elements of the list in a set.
2. create a new list.
3. iterate the set, then put each element of the set into the new list.
4. return the new list.
   done.